# Excel checkboxes created using VBA out of proportion

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a company wide file that has checkboxes created using VBA.

The problem: THese checkboxes are displayed based on a value selected from a dropdown, when a selection is made from the dropdown is made checkboxes are displayed. However the width of the checkbox doesn't show the full text that needs to be displayed.

Is there something that can be adjusted to fix this problem?

```
Dim cb As Object
    For Each cb In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, cb.Name, "CheckBox") > 0 Then
            cb.Object.Value = False
            cb.Visible = False
        End IF
If Left(Range("Req_Type").Value, 3) = "LCL" Then
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Caption = "L001"
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True
ElseIf Left(Range("Req_Type").Value, 3) = "JFS" Then
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Caption = "L002"
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Caption = "L042"
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Caption = "L043"
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Value = False
ElseIf Left(Range("Req_Type").Value, 3) = "PCB" Then
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Caption = "L300"
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Caption = "L301"
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Caption = "L302"
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Caption = "L303"
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Value = False
ElseIf Left(Range("Req_Type").Value, 4) = "REIT" Then
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Caption = "P001"
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Caption = "P200"
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Caption = "P201"
    Sheet1.CheckBox3.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Caption = "P202"
    Sheet1.CheckBox4.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox5.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox5.Caption = "P003"
    Sheet1.CheckBox5.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox6.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox6.Caption = "P204"
    Sheet1.CheckBox6.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox7.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox7.Caption = "P205"
    Sheet1.CheckBox7.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox8.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox8.Caption = "R003"
    Sheet1.CheckBox8.Value = False
ElseIf Left(Range("Req_Type").Value, 3) = "SDM" Then
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Caption = "L001"
    Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = False
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Visible = True
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Caption = "L600"
    Sheet1.CheckBox2.Value = False
```

Example of problem:
[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Hello. Have you tried anything to adjust the width of the checkbox?

Comment: Might be more useful to show the code which creates the checkboxes.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added the full code. Thanks

Comment: @Robby How do i change the width of the checkbox?

Comment: `cb.Width = 50` or `Sheet1.CheckBox1.Width = 50` for example.  It looks like you haven't closed off your `For Each` loop before you start setting specific checkboxes visible though - that may cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width via the `Width` property.  I'd also propose creating a sub to apply the caption and value so you can cut down on the bulk of your code.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cb As Object, v

    For Each cb In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        'safer to use this to detect checkboxes
        ' in case names are changed...
        If TypeName(cb.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            cb.Object.Value = False
            cb.Visible = True
            cb.Width = 50  '<<< set size here
        End If
    Next cb

    'need to move this outside of your For Each loop
    v = Range("Req_Type").Value
    Select Case True
        Case v Like "LCL*"
            SetUp Sheet1.CheckBox1, "L001", True
        Case v Like "JFS*"
            SetUp Sheet1.CheckBox1, "L002", False
            SetUp Sheet1.CheckBox2, "L042", False
            SetUp Sheet1.CheckBox3, "L043", False
        Case v Like "PCB*"
        '...etc
        '...etc
    End Select

End Sub

'Configure a checkbox with caption and value
'  could optionally set size here, maybe as a function of caption length
Sub SetUp(cb As Object, cbCaption As String, cbValue As Boolean)
    With cb
        .Visible = True 'since you always do this...
        .Caption = cbCaption
        .Value = cbValue
        '.Width = Len(cbCaption) * 5 'for example
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , i have added the following suggested code to my file however now when i select a value from the dropdown(Req_Type) none of the dropdowns are showing . Link to code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/D7aDQvg9

Comment: If you can share a copy of your workbook (remove any sensitive info) then I can help you debug your code, but i can't help much just by looking at your code.